# Gensim ImportError in PyCharm: No module named scipy.sparse

Tags: python, scipy, pycharm, lda, gensim

I am on Mac OS X 10.8.3 (Mountain Lion) and am trying to run a script in PyCharm.  Python 2.7.2 is installed, I have installed Canopy and Gensim.  I just do not understand what could be causing the error that I'm getting.

```
scipy.__version__
```

shows that v 0.11 is installed.

Here is the entirety of my output following a run of the script:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python "/util/LSA/Base LSA.py"

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/util/LSA/Base LSA.py", line 8, in <module>
    from gensim import corpora, models, similarities, matutils
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/gensim-0.8.6-py2.7.egg/gensim/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    import utils, matutils, interfaces, corpora, models, similarities
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/gensim-0.8.6-py2.7.egg/gensim/matutils.py", line 20, in <module>
    import scipy.sparse
ImportError: No module named scipy.sparse

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: how did you install scipy?

Comment: @MattDMo Not sure, Canopy maybe?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd suggest using the [Python.org](http://www.python.org/download/) version of Python, not the one that came with OSX, as there are some issues that are most easily overcome by installing the latest version - 2.7.4 in the case of the 2.x branch. Don't worry about breaking anything, both versions will happily coexist together. Once you have that, you can install the latest [NumPy](http://sourceforge.net/projects/numpy/files/NumPy/1.7.1/) and [SciPy](http://sourceforge.net/projects/scipy/files/scipy/0.12.0/) binaries (get the 10.6 `dmg` files). NumPy is required for SciPy to work.

Make sure you set up PyCharm to work with the new version of Python, and double-check that your modules are installed in the right `site-packages` directory (it should be `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/`). You can always copy all of the files in your `/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/` directory to the one I just mentioned, as the major.minor version of Python (2.7) is still the same. Then, you should be good to go. You will likely want to symlink `/usr/local/bin/python` to `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python` (it may be already) to make an easier shebang line, and don't forget to put `/usr/local/bin` in front of `/usr/bin` in your `PATH` for when you do command-line work, and for `#!/usr/bin/env python` shebangs. Good luck!